# Should I query the database for the JWT user in the middleware in Express.js?"

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I have a Node.js application where I'm using Passport.js with JWT strategy. After providing a JWT to the client, the user may become a canceled user. However, since they obtained the JWT beforehand, they can continue making requests to other endpoints until the JWT expires. In this case, is it reasonable to check the user's status in the middleware layer of Passport.js by making an additional database query, or is there a different approach?

```
const passportStrategy = (passport: {
  use: (arg0: passportJWT.Strategy) => void;
}) => {
  passport.use(
    new JWTStrategy(
      {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_AUTH_KEY!,
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      async (
        req: Request,
        payload: any,
        done: passportJWT.VerifiedCallback
      ) => {
        const src = DataSourceFactory.source;
         //db query in here

        try {
          
          });

          
          return done(null, user);
        } catch (findUserError) {
          return done(findUserError);
        }
      }
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: makes sense to issue JWT only if its not cancelled user

Comment: @sid "I think you misunderstood me. We issued a JWT for a valid user, but if the user gets banned or is later canceled, they can still use the previously issued JWT. For this reason, I need to make a request to the database in the middleware to check the user's status."

Comment: how long its valid for?

Comment: @sid "Unfortunately, my manager insists on a 60-minute duration. Personally, I would keep the expiration time between 5 to 10 minutes."

Comment: "However, even if it were 5 or 10 minutes, I wouldn't want someone who has been canceled to make requests to endpoints for that duration (:"

Comment: "I guess I need to query the database; there seems to be no other way. I'm inclined to think that JWT is not a great tool for session management."

Comment: Your server could maintain a cache of recently banned users (those banned within the last 60 minutes) and when you decrypt the JWT and see which user it is, you could then compare that against the in-memory list of banned users.  I'm assuming there shouldn't be a long list of users banned within the last 30 minutes so that data should fit into memory just fine and the comparison in memory should be faster than a DB lookup.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks,  "It seems like you're saying, 'Keep track of users who have been canceled in Redis or store the tokens of logged-out users in Redis, and query Redis in the middleware layer.' Is this correct?"

Comment: Redis if you have clustered servers.  If you have a single instance server, you can just keep it in server memory (perhaps no need for redis).  Just remember to age away the cancelled tokens after they would have expired on their own so they don't accumulate forever.  That could be a once every few hours timer that sweeps out any tokens that are older than an hour.

Comment: @jfriend00 "If there is only one server but multiple instances of the backend application running within Docker for scaled purposes, does it not make sense to use Redis in this scenario? I don't understand."

Comment: Your terminology confuses the heck out of me.  If you have more than one instance of any server process that all need access to the same short term data, then yes use redis (or any database of your choosing) to store that data in one central place that each instance can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might seem like a right approach but doing a db query in the middleware defeats the purpose of making it sessionless.
There are alternative standard solutions depending on your use case and the severity of the issue -

1. **Use two tokens,** refresh tokens with higher expiry time and access token with smaller expiry
   In this approach, when user/client tries to fetch a new access token (JWT token) using the refresh token, you can return error based on db query.
   In this approach, db calls happen only when a new access token is fetched.
2. **Maintain a list of cancelled users in a cache -**

   ```
          async (
            req: Request,
            payload: any,
            done: passportJWT.VerifiedCallback
          ) => {
            const src = DataSourceFactory.source;
            const cacheUser = redisCache.get("cancelled_user_" + "<user id from token>")
            if (cacheUser) {
               // throw error
            }
            // Else do your stuff  
              return done(null, user);
            } catch (findUserError) {
              return done(findUserError);
            }
          }
   ```

In the second approach, you're just querying over cancelled users and that too from cache. The expiry of the cache could be same as the expiry if the token.

Comment: I actually don't like using JWTs for session management, and unfortunately, I think they are often used in a way that deviates from their intended purpose. Therefore, sometimes it's necessary to use them in a stateful manner.

Comment: Agreed, if you are creating sessions then its not required to have JWT as the token.

Comment: setting req.user = user is not a problem, but if user information is not needed in a specific endpoint, fetching detailed user data from the database using a SELECT query when it is available in the request object might impose a performance overhead. Is this weighty in terms of performance?"

Comment: Yes. That is why db query is happening only in refresh token and not in access token (regular token) which is used in most of the endpoints.

Comment: The method you explained is nice, and I liked it. However, a person can fall into the 'cancelledUser' state while the session is still open. Therefore, would it be more reasonable to set the accessToken duration to 1 minute? If it's too long, even if the user is cancelled, they could still use the endpoint until the JWT becomes invalid or make requests to the refresh token endpoint. What do you recommend regarding the duration

Comment: You've got it correctly - this is widely used practice to use a short period. But if you are working with transactions, financial related stuff one should prefer using state maintained in db or cache like cancelled user.

Comment: "I explained below what I did in response. I would appreciate it if you could review and get back to me."

Answer (score 0):

1: only for postgres and typeorm example.

- In general, here's what I've done: I check whether the token or user is invalid in the Node.js middleware layer for each request, preferably using Redis. This way, I maintain the accessToken duration around 15 minutes and the refreshToken duration around 30 minutes. Also, when querying the database, the middleware dynamically shapes 'req.user' based on the specific requirements of the current endpoint. For example, considering a PostgreSQL scenario using TypeORM, I can choose which fields to retrieve in the query using TypeORM's 'select' feature. When sending a request in the middleware, I shape the 'select' part according to the request's needs, resulting in 'req.user = dynamicDbUser.' It seems like a good approach to me.

My database query in the middle layer

```
  use: (jwtName: string, arg0: passportJWT.Strategy) => void;
}) => {
  passport.use(
    'jwt',
    new JWTStrategy(
      {
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_ACCESS_KEY!,
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      async (
        req: Request,
        payload: UserPayload,
        done: passportJWT.VerifiedCallback
      ) => {
        const src = DataSourceFactory.source;
        const sessionRepo = src.getRepository(SessionEntity);

        try {
       HERE:   const dynamicSelect = createDynamicSelect(req.selectField);
          const session = await sessionRepo.findOne({
          HERE:  select: dynamicSelect,
            relations: {
              user: true,
              token: true,
              member: true,
            },
            where: [
              {
                user: {
                  publicId: payload.id,
                  expired: {
                    date: MoreThan(new Date(new Date().getTime())),
                  },
                },
                status: SessionType.Active,
                token: {
                  token: payload.jti,
                  operation: TokenOperationType.loginAfterValidRegistration,
                },
              },
            ],
          });

          if (!session) {
            return done(null, false);
          }

          return done(null, session);
        } catch (findUserError) {
          return done(findUserError, false);
        }
      }
    )
  );
```

- To configure the structure for determining what comes in the dynamic 'select,' I use the following router. If I specify 'user,' I place the user information of the person currently performing the operation in the 'req.user' in that service. If I don't need it for other endpoints, it becomes `'Is.loggedIn(DynamicFieldType.none).`

```
      `${this.path}`,
      Is.loggedIn(DynamicFieldType.user),
      Is.hasPermission(UserType.BestNetAdmin, UserType.Admin),
      ValidationMiddleware(PortalUserCreateDto),
      checkUserTypeMiddleware,
      this.portalUser.createHandler
    );
```

- "Of course, when receiving a 401, it indicates that an invalid token or an invalid user request has been made in the middleware. In my application, when I encounter this, I send a request to the refresh token endpoint because the purpose is to obtain a new token. However, if, for any reason, the refresh token is invalid (invalid user, etc.), I throw a 403 error. Additionally, to mitigate XSS and CSRF attacks to some extent, I store the token in memory and the refresh token in cookies. This is the design I've come up with as a junior backend developer. If you think this overall structure is a good approach, please share your thoughts. Thank you."